# Why my HtmlUnit Login function does not work

Tags: java, spring, htmlunit

I am trying to submit my account info into this page (https://yoyaku.sports.metro.tokyo.lg.jp/user/view/user/homeIndex.html?te-uniquekey=1887c057141). But for some reason, when I use click method in navigateToOldVotePage function in below, it shows me username and password is empty error. I cannot figure out why the entered information is not submitted...

```
public static HtmlPage loginToVotePage(WebClient webClient, Account account) {
        HtmlPage loginPage = navigateToLoginPage(webClient);
        HtmlPage loginPage = navigateToOldLoginPage(webClient);
        return navigateToOldVotePage(loginPage, account);
    }

    private static HtmlPage navigateToOldLoginPage(WebClient webClient) {
        try {
            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(OLD_HOME_URL);
            final List<FrameWindow> window = page.getFrames();
            final HtmlPage pageTwo = (HtmlPage) window.get(1).getEnclosedPage();
            HtmlAnchor loginAnchor = pageTwo.getFirstByXPath(OLD_LOGIN_XPATH);
            return loginAnchor.click();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error happend duing navigating to login page: " + e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static HtmlPage navigateToOldVotePage(HtmlPage page, Account account) {
        try {
            HtmlInput userInput = page.getElementByName("userId");
            HtmlInput pwdInput = page.getElementByName("password");
            userInput.setValueAttribute(account.toeiId);
            pwdInput.setValueAttribute(account.password);
            
            HtmlAnchor submitLogin = page.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id='disp']/center/form/table[5]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/a");
            HtmlPage loggedIn = submitLogin.click();

            // 168...: /web/rsvWUA_Action.do

            System.out.println(loggedIn.asXml());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error happend duing loging process: " + e);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Have you been debug before ask question?  Method  ```loginToVotePage```  is static ,  and according to your code snippet it seems like  login info redirect scenario . Not sure how the code run  and  your did not clarify the account info is missing at which method or line ?  If your are using spring as network framewok that you can try to modify your method as local method and provide minimal runable demo that it would be more clear got your main issue.